# SQL Query handle multiple WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I intend to generate report through web interface.

```
My page content two field:
----------------------

Gender: Male Female (radio button)

Age: 10 to 20 (Select list)

------------------
```

How can I write query, they handle both situation, if user provide only "Gender" base WHERE clause or required gender or Age base WHERE clause.

I am want to write single query handle both situation.

Please help me

Regards,

Comment: You might have heard of the `AND` keyword.  Like, `where gender = 'male' and age between 10 and 20`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read FAQ, How to Ask and help center as a start

Comment: OK my dear Friend!

But please find me answer.

Comment: IF user provide single parameter how can I handle this situation?

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly it is you want. It sounds like you want a solution in a programming language, but you don't specify any programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `and`:

```
select *
from   yourTable
where  gender = 'Male'
and    age between 10 and 20
```

If it is unsure whether a user enters a value, try `or` and a `null` check. You can do the same for `gender`:

```
select *
from   yourTable
where  gender = 'Male'
and    (age is null or age between 10 and 20)
```

Comment: if user do not provide age field, how can I handle?

Comment: @ZahidHussain: Need more help?

Comment: Thank you my Dear Friend @Patrick Hofman,

Thank you once again, giving me your precious time and knowledge,

I hope you have good with nice pleasure.

Best regards,

Comment: @ZahidHussain: You are welcome. Since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked best by checking the checkmark before the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your base query should be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE 1=1
```

And you should add clauses (" AND gender = something", " AND age between something and something") based on the parameters provided by user.

If the user does not select any parameters, the base query should work fine. If the user provides a parameter or both, the query becomes something like:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Customer 
WHERE 1=1
AND gender = "male"
```